# Auto Increment Index Field For Create and Update

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to create an unique auto increment index field that is re-generated on both inserts and updates. I need it so that a client can send a server an integer and get back all outdated (created or updated) records. Something that would allow:

```
Insert Record A (Record A 'touched' set to '1')  
Insert Record B (Record B 'touched' set to '2')
Update Record A (Record A 'touched' set to '3')
Update Record B (Record B 'touched' set to '4')
```

I'm using both Postgresql and Sqlite (production and development) and would ideally like a solution that will work under both. What is the best way to add something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: a) I'm curious about that business logic. b) sounds like the need for a trigger.

Comment: @jcolebrand The purpose is to do a offline pull onto mobile devices of a data set. The pull needs to grab all created and modified records since the last pull.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to develop and test with a different DBMS than the one used in production.

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine a sequence with some mechanism to trigger the increment for an `update`. For postgres

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, description text, touched serial);
```

Then either:

- create a trigger to set `touched` = `default` on an update
  or
- get all your updates going through an API that also actions the increment

auto-increment is [implemented differently for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) so you will have to work around that - perhaps by inserting/deleting a new row each time you update a row, and using the rowid of that temporary row to update `touched`.